# __slots__ of date class of datetime module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I do some works relate to date class. So, I read datetime.py in C:\Python34\Lib. I am on Python 3.4 by the way. I stumble upon these line codes:

```
class date:   
    __slots__ = '_year', '_month', '_day'

    def __new__(cls, year, month=None, day=None):        
        if (isinstance(year, bytes) and len(year) == 4 and
            1 <= year[2] <= 12 and month is None):  # Month is sane
            # Pickle support
            self = object.__new__(cls)
            self.__setstate(year)
            return self
        _check_date_fields(year, month, day)
        self = object.__new__(cls)
        self._year = year
        self._month = month
        self._day = day
        return self
```

......

```
    @property
    def year(self):
        """year (1-9999)"""
        return self._year

    @property
    def month(self):
       """month (1-12)"""
       return self._month

    @property
    def day(self):
        """day (1-31)"""
        return self._day
```

I understand that `__slots__` denying creation of `__dict__` in instance. As I read in examples and documents `__slots__` doesn't deny direct access to instant/class attribute. However, in case of date class, I tried to access _year, _month, _date from instance. It errors out. For example:

```
In [32]: from datetime import date    
In [33]: mydate = date(2019, 3, 10)
In [34]: mydate._year
>>>AttributeError Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-31-8de5c748f55b> in <module>() ----> 1 mydate._year
AttributeError: 'datetime.date' object has no attribute '_year'
```

I know `'_'` variables mean for NOT direct access and @property year, month, day are their getter functions.  However, I thought `'_'` variables are still accessible if one wants to even in case of declaring `__slots__`

I write a Foo class as below to test:

```
class Foo:
    __slots__ = ('_bar',)

    def __new__(cls):    
        self = super().__new__(cls)
        self._bar = 'barz'
        return self

    @property
    def bar(self):
        return self._bar

In [35]: f = Foo()

In [36]: f._bar
Out[36]: 'barz'
```

Instance f of this Foo class has no issue to access _bar although using `__slots__` and @property

Why does Foo class is able to access `_bar` declaring in `__slots__` while date class error on accessing `_year`?

Comment: Because you aren't using that implement of datetime, you are using the C implementation: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_datetimemodule.c

Comment: thanks for the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the bottom of the file you were reading, there are these lines:

```
try:
    from _datetime import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

This tries to import any available names from the `_datetime` module. The `_datetime` module is an "accelerator" module written in C. It provides faster implementations of some of the functions and types defined in Python code in `datetime.py`. As commented by [juanpa.arrivillaga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5014455/juanpa-arrivillaga) on your question, [here's the C source for `_datetime`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0e1f1f01058bd4a9b98cfe443214adecc019a38c/Modules/_datetimemodule.c).

The attributes you try to access don't exist in the C version of the `date` type. As the underscore prefix should hint to you, the attributes are not part of the public API for `datetime.date`, so even if you were getting the Python implementation you'd be messing around with internals that could change without warning in a future version of Python.

Comment: I know `'_'` lowercase classes are implemented in C. I also see those import lines at the bottom. However, I thought it is only for methods and class doesn't exist in the python codes in datetime.py. Is any reason for those date class in python codes existing in datetime.py while `_datetime` already implemented it?

Comment: Some library modules *require* a C module to function, so those required things are imported at the top of the file so the Python code can use them later. In this case though, everything is done in Python first, then replaced by faster alternatives written in C. If your build of Python doesn't have the `_datetime` module for some reason, it will still work. There are probably other ways the file could be organized to achieve the same results, but this is a common way to do it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I clicked accept on your answer